# How to "deactivate" plugin if error in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am running SQL commands and when there is an error I want to deactivate my plugin. Do I do that with `wp_die` or is there some other preferred method?

Comment: this may help you http://blog.iredlof.com/2009/06/how-to-de-activate-wordpress-plugin-using-php-code/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that plugin activation/deactivation is controlled by the wp_options table in the DB.

You might consider a second MySQL call that deactivates the specific plugin. You can get all active plugins using this:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins';
```

You can update the list with something like this:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'a:0:{}' WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins';
```

Obviously, you'd want to modify this to target the specific plugin.

I saw this method used [here](http://perishablepress.com/press/2008/02/18/quickly-disable-or-enable-all-wordpress-plugins-via-the-database/), in which the author is describing how to deactivate ALL plugins via a MySQL query. Hope this helps.